# PHP and MySQL remote host

Tags: mysql, php, remote-access

How to run a PHP script which needs to connect to a MySQL at a remote host?

When I run this:

```
    $dbHost = "example.com";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "pass";
    $dbDatabase = "some_db";


    $dbi = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
    mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $dbi) or die ("Could not select database.");
```

...I get:

```
    Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.1.1' (using password: YES) in /home/foo/bar.php on line 9
```

What settings should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default MySQL users are allowed to access databases from localhost only. You need to add access from your IP or all IPs by using [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* to foouser@1.2.3.4 IDENTIFIED BY 'password for user';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON foodatabasename.* TO foouser@1.2.3.4;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```